# sum of piecewise functions - twice continously differentiable?

Tags: functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let f be a cubic interpolant. I want to express it as a sum of "basis functions" multipled by interpolation values. That is,

$$ f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} S_i(x)f_i $$
where $f_i$ are the interpolation values at the points $x_i$ and
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
S_i(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\tilde{S}_i(x)}{f_i}&\text{ for }x_i\le x<x_{i+1}\\
0&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray} $$
The $\tilde{S}_i(x)$ are the piecewise cubic splines, which satisfy $$ \tilde{S}_i(x_i) = f_i \\ \tilde{S}_i(x_{i+1}) = f_{i+1} \\ \tilde{S}_i^{'}(x_{i+1}) = \tilde{S}_{i+1}^{'}(x_i) \\ \tilde{S}_i^{''}(x_{i+1}) = \tilde{S}_{i+1}^{''}(x_i)$$

Example: For $x \in [x1,x2[$, we have $f(x) = S_0(x)f_0 + 0 + 0 = \tilde{S}_0(x)$ which, I think, is correct.

Per definition of cubic interpolant, I know that f is twice continuously differentiable, but I am not sure if my notation above represents this fact.